# how to make a relations between angular 1 components?

Tags: angularjs, redux

i'm looking for some solution to work with angular 1.5 components in a way that a change in one component will change something in other component in another place in the tree.
what so you think is the best solution?
rootScope?
redux?
events?
some other global variable?

Comment: You can enable communication between each other component by providing an object mapping for the `require` property. `require: { otherCtrl: '^other'},`

Answer (score 1):

If you want your own service without redux or anything else, you can implement a service like :

```
angular.module("my_service", [])
  .factory("Message", function() {
     var messages = {
     // m1: [],
     // m2: []
     };

     function receive(message, messageHandler) {
       if (!Array.isArray(messages[message])) {
         messages[message] = [];
       }
       messages[message].push(messageHandler);
     }

     function send(messageName, message) {
       if (Array.isArray(messages[messageName])) {
         messages[messageName].forEach(function(messageHandler) {
           messageHandler(message);
         });
       } else {
         console.warn("sent message", message, "is not in the message list...");
       }
     }

     return {
       send: send,
       receive: receive
     };
   }
 });
```

And in somewhere else you can create two controllers for example :

```
angular.module("app", ["my_service"])
.controller("app1", function(Message) {
  Message.receive("sthHappened", function(whatHappened) {
    console.log("app1 says :", whatHappened);
  });
})
.controller("app2", function(Message) {
  Message.send("sthHappened", "app2 initiated");
});
```

Basically you register a function in order to execute when a message received, and a trigger when something happened in order to execute the registered functions.
Of course you may need to make some additions according to what you need and improve performance or async op in order to break the sequential execution, but this the basic structure of a publisher-subscriber mechanism in order to create a messaging channel between your controllers or directives or any functions.